# What's the best practice for changing migration timestamp so that it changes the order a migration is run in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-migrations

I'm trying to perform some migrations, but the code stops when it encounters an hstore extension. My `AddHstoreExtension` migration file is currently the last migration in order of timestamps. Should I change the timestamp to get it to run first? What's best practice?

Comment: You can simply rename the file with a "minor" timestamp.

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: I don't really think you need to worry about that much about the best practice that much. Migrations are not actually supposed to hang around in your code base forever. As soon as you have run the migration in production it can be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prefix of the *file name* is whats used to determine order, not the timestamp on the file itself just so you know, but yes that would work.

Remember you can:

```
rails db:rollback <number of migrations>
```

To undo any you've applied.

Comment: Isn't the prefix of the file name the timestamp?

Comment: It is a timestamp, but most filesystems also have timestamps for when a file was last touched as well. That's what I was saying your don't have to touch.

Comment: Okay, so what isn't clear to me in your answer is, when I run ```rails db:rollback <number of migrations>``` Don't I then have to run ```rails db:migrate``` which then runs the program in the sequence of timestamps prepended to the beginning of the file? Does ```rails db:rollback <number of migrations>``` solve this issue?

Comment: The reason to run `db:rollback` is if the migrations you need to change have already been applied. If you haven't applied them yet, you can just go fix them, change them, do whatever you want to them on disk, and then run `db:migrate`. But if you've already applied them, you need to `db:rollback` *before* you go about fixing them.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same type of situation once. I had to run one before another. Looked for some best practices. Didn't find one, so I just reordered the timestamp rather than just doing the hole process again. It's a bit hacky but serves the purpose.

But first, remember o rollback to the point that need to be modified.

Comment: Reordered it by just renaming the file?

Comment: Yeah just reordering.